# What is the English for the Swedish word 'snippa'?

Tags: single-word-requests

This report appeared in yesterday's *Observer* - page 22.

[Little boys have a word for theirs. Now Swedish girls do too...](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/aug/01/sweden-girls-genitals-feminist-invention-snippa-vagina).

It begins: *I only ever speak English to our three-year-old daughter, and my wife only speaks Swedish to her. The one exception is the word snippa. It’s Swedish for a girl’s genitals, the female equivalent of snopp, meaning “willy”, and I can’t find an English word that does the job.*

What is the equivalent English word?

Comment: Come on, you should know translation requests aren't on-topic unless you define the word in a lot of detail. And if you want a single-word-request, then you need to explain how the English word will be *used*. -1

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to refer to an external site. And while the Guardian-Observer's website may not disappear, they could easily change their URL schema. Please edit in enough detail to make the question stand alone (just the "dry yourself" portion is probably enough to satisfy @curiousdannii's comment too).

Comment: Can you give more details about the nuances of the word you are seeking? Diminutive, child-talk, euphemism sure. But is it a silly word or a misdirection. Is it old-fashioned or new? (I am not BrE but) What's wrong with 'tuppence'? 'fanny'? 'coochie'?

Comment: @Mitch I've never personally heard of the first or last ones. The middle one, in Britain, is considered downright obscene, and no parents are going to teach that to their little one. Interestingly, regarding *tuppence*, whist I've never heard that, I have heard of *ha'penny* (half penny), as in *keep your hand on your ha'penny* - though it is very dated now - possibly pre-WW2.

Comment: @WS2 My only evidence for tuppence is ... [from ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25839/is-it-true-that-tuppence-refers-to-a-womans-vagina-in-british-english-slang) but people seem to say it is out of date. So you're not that old after all!

Comment: @Mitch Some consideration should be given to *Lulu* - based on the infamous [Honolulu penny](https://www.johnwinter.net/jw/2014/11/the-vulgar-penny/)

Comment: @WS2 ?? I couldn't find anything on 'lulu' or anything in that link that justifies 'honolulu penny' having a special meaning. It mentions it at the end but doesn't explain a thing. What do 'lulu' and 'honolulu penny' mean and why?

Comment: @Mitch The trident is "on her lulu" i.e. *Honolulu*. They were always known as *Honolulu pennies* when I was a lad.

Comment: @WS2 Wait... are you saying that 'lulu' (or the longer phrase) is like an English version of snippa? Exactly the thing you are asking about?

Comment: @Mitch Just that the fact of Honolulu pennies suggests something like that might once have been the case. I'm sure the organ in question gets called all kinds of things by people when drunk.

Answer (score 3):

I think the first thing to say is that an answer to this question will be influenced by geographical location.

US and UK English culture for example are often different with regard to this type of nomenclature as are different areas and subcultures within those countries.

I made a google search for  *polite words for vagina* and found this British discussion that may be of interest. Clearly no-one has yet come up with a definitive answer.

'noonie' is one that I have heard.

> from Mumsnet:
>
> http://www.netmums.com/coffeehouse/children-parenting-190/toddlers-pre-schoolers-12-months-4-years-59/964262-nice-names-vagina-all.html

Comment: Why search for polite names for 'vagina' rather than 'vulva'?

Answer (score 2):

> 'lulu'

is sometimes used as a euphemism for a girl's genitals.

[image: text describing lulu and honolulu penny]

'Honolulu penny', a reference to a particular British coinage of the 1800's whose picture could be interpreted lewdly,

[image: seated woman holding trident that by coincidence seems to come out of her lap]

is a similar sounding term; it is unclear which came first, Honolulu shortened to lulu or lulu hidden within or rhyming with existing term 'Honoulu'.

'lulu' or 'loo loo' seem to have many other current slang uses and may well be out of date. But phonetically it sounds like many other childish euphemisms.

Comment: I have awarded an upvote for the picture etc, though I did provide you with the starter for this idea. One thing I feel sure about is that this has no connection whatever with *loo* meaning "toilet". That has an entirely different etymology.

Comment: It is also important to point out that the "honolulu pennies" were quite rare  - at least by the time I was at school in the 1950s. On most pennies at that time Britannia had her trident resting "on her knee" - thus if one saw one of the kind above it was deemed "on her lulu" hence "honolulu".

Answer (score 0):

Now in America this means butt but in other regions **fanny** is a synonym. One I have heard in America quite a bit has been **vajayjay**. Also **kitty, flower, and peach**.

Comment: None of those is the kind of word a three-year-old would use to describe their genitals.

Comment: You evidently know very different children than I, however that doesn't mean it isn't so.

Comment: But they are hardly words that a polite middle-class parent would encourage their three-year-old to use, are they?